# AuthorizeRole="Admin" not working in mvc3 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

- I have membership provider setup in an mvc3 application.
- I ported it from the local sql express app_data/aspnetdb.mdf to a local server 2008 instance
  (this is currently working fine for logins/etc, and [Authorize] SomeMethod()
- I recently added 1 new aspnet_roles ("Admin") and 1 new entry in the  aspnet_UsersInRoles assoc. w/my username.

Role Table:

> ApplicationId RoleId  RoleName    LoweredRoleName Description
>   3F96CA96-CCB3-4780-8038-AF3CCE0BD4F2  9B5B798D-E56E-4144-A12C-7C8945FCB413    Admin   admin   Administrator

UsersInRoles:

> UserId    RoleId
>   58974159-E60E-4185-AD00-F8024C7C5974  9B5B798D-E56E-4144-A12C-7C8945FCB413

**Q1:** Why does the following code not let me into this controller action?

```
    [Authorize]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]  // !!! This is keeping me out...commented out I can get in but I'm set as "Admin" and have tried lower case "admin" as well.
    public ActionResult SomeMethod()
    {}
```

**Q1a:**  Is there another a role provider connection string that I have to setup in the web config to get this to work?

Comment: have you provided the correct connection parameters in `<membership><providers>...</providers></membership>` in your web.config

Comment: Hi all!  My membership string for roleManager was messed up.  It was setup to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please post parts of your web.config regarding membership and role providers. This sounds like your application name isn't set properly.

```
 <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="Your Application Name here" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

**Edit**
Your application name isn't set. It needs to be set to something and it must match the application name in your database table: aspnet_Applications

If you web config has applicationName="TestApp" /> then your database table also needs to have TestApp in the aspnet_Applications table

Comment: I just psted the roleManager section.  was set to false...the application name while defaulted to / looks to be defined ok in the webconfig as well as in the database.

Comment: RoleManager config section was not setup properly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ApplicationId is the same you are probably using a different applicationId, check [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1337914.aspx/1) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in order to pin point your problem :

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod() {

    if (!User.IsInRole("Admin")) 
        throw new SecurityException("User is not an admin.");

}
```

If you get an exception, it means that there is problem with your Membership Provider or you're not in `admin` role or your applicationid was configured different as suggested below.

These are some of the possibilities.